# MATLAB Constructors

Tags: matlab

I am having difficulty deciding what is the best way to use the constructors in MATLAB. 
The majority of examples provided are as follows:

```
classdef ClassA < handle
    properties
        m_a;
        m_b;   
    end 

    methods
        function obj = ClassA(a,b)
            obj.m_a = a;
            obj.m_b = b;          
    end 
end
```

But suppose that a and b are of other classes ClassB and ClassC

Then the constructor could also be written as:

```
methods
    function obj = ClassA(a,b)
         obj.m_a = ClassB(a);
         obj.m_b = ClassC(b);          
end
```

Which way would be the preferred convention?

Answer (score 0):

There is no *preferred* convention in this case. Although they look similar, your two example are not exactly equivalent. It will all depend on how `a` and `b` will be presented to the constructor of `classA`.

In your first case:
`a` and `b` have to be respectively `classB` and `classC` when they are send to `classA`.

In your second case:
`a` and `b` are not instances of `classB/C`, but simply the typical parameter needed for the constructor of `classB/C` to instantiate the objects. Let's say they are of class `double` for the sake of argument.

So

```
     case 1:                    case 2:
variable | type            variable | type
    a      classB              a      double
    b      classC              b      double

then in classA
 obj.m_a   classB           obj.m_a   classB
 obj.m_b   classC           obj.m_b   classC
```

As you can see, it makes little difference in the end for `classA`. The choice should be more driven by what **the calling function** (the function which will call the constructor of `classA`) has to handle.

- If you calling function make use of `a` and `b` as object of class `classB` and `classC`, then it make sense for the calling function to have these already available, then send that to the constructor of `classA` when it calls it. In this case you would choose your first option.
- If the calling function has nothing to do with `classB` and `classC` (these classes are only useful for or inside `classA`), then there is no need for the caller function to handle this types. Keep `a` and `b` as simple as you need, and only instantiate `classB` and `classC` in the contructor of `classA` as in your second example.

---

As a side note, be aware of some details of the `handle classes`. Specifically the Matlab [doc](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) says:

> **Initializing Properties to Unique Values** MATLAB assigns properties to the specified default values only once when MATLAB loads the class
>   definition. Therefore, **if you initialize a property value with a
>   handle-class constructor, MATLAB calls this constructor only once and
>   every instance references the same handle object**. If you want a
>   property value to be initialized to a new instance of a handle object
>   each time you create an object, assign the property value in the
>   constructor.

It means if you choose your option 2, and `classB/C` are also handle class which do not require an input argument, **DO NOT** try to shortcut and declare them this way:

```
classdef ClassA < handle
    properties
        m_a = ClassB() ;    %// never do that if ClassB is a handle class
        m_b = classC() ;    %// never do that if ClassC is a handle class
    end 
methods
    function obj = ClassA(a,b)
         %// do you other stuff
end
```

Instead, initialize your variable **in the constructor** (as you did in your example) and not in the property definitions. I know this is not what you did but if you choose your option 2 it would be easy to fall into this trap thinking to simplify things.
If you were to do this, no error will show up but any other instance of `classB` you could declare/create in later code would always reference **the very same object** that was created the first time in your property definition. (*Even other instances of* `classA` *would have their properties all referencing the same unique* `classB` *object.*)